# Parse a text file, create a new instance of a song class, and add a song to a vector<Song*>

Tags: c++

I have asked a question simular to this a week or so ago. What was said before brought me into many problems because I forgot to mention something.

The problem is that I have a text file that contains hundreds of lines that all look like:

song_number|song_title|song_release_date||*ignore this one*|0|1|0|1|0|0|0|0

the numbers represent what type of music the song is. If there is a 1 it would represent a certain genre and if 0 it would not represent that type of genre. The genre at(0) for example is the same for every song and same with the rest of the genres.

Now I need to create a new instance of a song class that has these parameters being:

(int song_number, string title, string release_date, vector genres)

I wish to parse the text file in 1 function, that function creating a new instance of the song class and then in the end adding it to a vector of type Song.

The idea is so that I can access any song based on song number so I can do something like 
songHolder->at(100)->get_song_title();

Thanks!!

Comment: Why a vector, and why a container of pointers and not of objects itelf?

Comment: So what do you want help with?

Comment: I have tried using the fscanf and i really didnt get very far. The | separator is giving me problems I want to tolkenize each line so I have each item separated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a couple of things:

1) Define a song class

```
class Song { /* STUFF */ }
```

2) Define an input (and probably an output iterator

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Song& data)        { /* STUFF */ }
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, Song const& data) { /* STUFF */ }
```

3) Then you just need to read the data from the file using the stream operator.

```
std::vector<Song>   songHolder;
std::ifstream       file("FileName");
Song                tmp;
while (file >> tmp)
{
    songHolder.push_back(tmp);
}
```

4) Now you should be able to access the songs in your vector:

```
std::cout << songHolder.at(100).get_song_title();
// or just dump the song
std::cout << songHolder.at(100);
```

Comment: This is a stupid technique, as the song titles might have whitespace in them.

Comment: @Oxsnarder: So what. It still works. The song title would be handled in the section above marked /* STUFF */. It can easily handle song titles with a space in them with 0 difficulty. PS. This is relatively basic stuff. Infact I would go further and say this is the bases of all streaming in C++.